# Mudar title da aba com script, como faz?

Tags: html, script

Quero que apareça só o nome do produto sem o nome do site, como eu uso uma plataforma pré pronta não da pra editar a tag `<title>`, por isso preciso usar um script pra fazer isso.

No momento aparece assim na aba do navegador "Nome Site - Nome Produto", quero colocar o nome do site no final ou mesmo tirar ele e deixar só o nome do produto que tá na tag "h1"

---

Quando coloco o script aparece "undefined" na aba

`document.title = document.getElementsByClassName('nomeDescricaoProduto').innerText;`

esse aqui é o que tem no html

```
<div class="nomeDescricaoProduto">

<h1> Nome do Produto </h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode pegar o nome do produto de duas formas: pelo `querySelector`, ou pelo próprio `getElementsByClassName` (o qual você já tentou usar).

**Pegando pelo `querySelector`**

Você pode usar uma query para pegar o `<h1>` que está dentro de um elemento qualquer que possuir a classe `nomeDescricaoProduto`:

```
document.title = document.querySelector('.nomeDescricaoProduto h1').innerText;
```

No entanto, o `querySelector` do JavaScript só retorna o primeiro elemento que ele acha, ou seja, ele não retorna uma lista, e por isso, não seria o adequado para caso tivesse mais descrições para serem capturadas.

Por isso, se desejar, você pode usar o `getElementsByClassName`.

**Pegando pelo `getElementsByClassName`**

Você também pode fazer da forma que você já colocou (como resposta). No seu caso estava retornando `undefined`, pois, você estava tentando pegar a propriedade (inexistente) `innerText` de uma *NodeList*, ou seja, uma *lista de nodes*. Portanto, se essa *div* é a única com essa classe, você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
document.title = document.getElementsByClassName('nomeDescricaoProduto')[0].innerText;
```

Em ambos os casos, se você quiser, você pode executar o método `trim` para remover todos os espaços em branco (talvez, desnecessários) da frente e de trás da string:

```
document.title = document.querySelector('.nomeDescricaoProduto h1').innerText.trim();
```

Ou

```
document.title = document.getElementsByClassName('nomeDescricaoProduto')[0].innerText.trim();
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: `document.title = document.getElementsByClassName('nomeDescricaoProduto')[0].innerText.trim();` isso mesmo que eu queria vlw

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
Você pode alterar o title da página atribuindo um novo valor ao `document.title`, e para pegar o texto dentro do `<h1>` basta obter da propriedade `innerText`, da seguinte maneira:

```
document.title = document.getElementById('produto').innerText;
```

Comment: Faltou mencionar que a solução do op não está funcionando porque ele está usando o `document.getElementsByClassName` que por sua vez retorna um vetor de classes, uma vez que classe não é única como o id e pode ser repetida.

Answer (score 0):

Você está pegando um array de classes com o `getElementsByClassName` o que é normal, visto que pode haver mais de uma classe com o mesmo nome, então isso retorna um array de classes, visto que as classes são usadas para repetir estilos/códigos para outros elementos.

Então dessa forma você deveria pegar o valor por `document.getElementsByClassName('nomeDescricaoProduto')[0].innerText;`

e a posição 0 apenas caso a div com a classe fosse a primeira. Se houver mais de uma div com a mesma classe, deverá ver qual é a ordem, para então colocar a posição.

Por isso sinto que você está fazendo da forma errada, pelo contexto do que você quer fazer, acredito que na verdade deveria ser o id e não a classe, pois o id é único e não se repete, então usaria:

```
document.getElementById('nomeDescricaoProduto').innerText;
```